# Wordpress installation from live site to localhost

Tags: installation, localhost

I just need to know if this is the only way to install wordpress from live to localhost.

I downloaded the files and database from live, then push the files folder to my htdocs folder, and uploaded the db through phpmyadmin and change the config file.

Upto this point I think im on correct side.

After entering `http://localhost/mylocalsite` URL in web browser site loads in correct way, however link seems to be still pointing the old (live site) URLs.

So for this I search my live site URLs in the DB like --  `http://www.mylivesite.com` and replace this with the `http://localhost/mylocalsite` URL.

So my question is if this is the correct way i am implementing it on my locals or some more appealing method i am missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update your `wp_options` table.

Look for `siteurl` and `home` and change their values to point to your localhost, that is, `http://localhost/mylocalsite`. This should be enough to make your site work again.

You don't need to find and replace all instances where the old url is present. For example you [should not change the `guid`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Important_GUID_Note) of your posts.

Alse read this post on [Moving Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress).

Comment: thx for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following MySQL query:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content,
'http://www.mylivesite.com',
'ttp://localhost/mylocalsite');
```

However, this doesn't replace any serialized URLs, which could cause problems. There's a [search and replace script](http://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) I use, which works well.

Comment: thx for the link ... serialize data is actually a prob creator while doing something like this in the db :(